# Excel (LibreOffice Calc) show blank cells but openpyxl shows values

Tags: python, pandas, validation, openpyxl, libreoffice-calc

I have a workbook sheet that shows the first 3 rows with data when opened with LibreOffice Calc.  If I use conditional formatting to set cell background color to red if a cell is blank, all cells in rows 4 and following show red.  When I read the spreadsheet with Pandas, I get 20 rows with rows 4 through 20 all blank.  When I read the spreadsheet with openpyxl, I also get 20 rows and  here is the interesting part: rows 4 through 20 have values in column AC (29).  That column has a data validation drop-down.  While no data shows up in LibrOffice Calc or Pandas, data shows up in openpyxl.  This appears to be a ghost of data that has been deleted.

I can delete blank rows in Pandas after I read the worksheet but the read_excel method throws up data validation errors for rows 4 through 20 before I can delete them. I would like to detect and remove the rows before read_excel.  Is there a way to detect this and remove the spurious rows using openpyxl?  I could then use openpyxl.load_workbook, delete the bad rows, and then use read_excel giving it the openpyxl workbook.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.  The items for the data validation were in a hidden column (AD) on the same sheet.